# Python: Splat/unpack operator * in python cannot be used in an expression?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking, pep448

Does anybody know the reasoning as to why the unary (`*`) operator cannot be used in an expression involving iterators/lists/tuples?

Why is it only limited to function unpacking? or am I wrong in thinking that?

For example:

```
>>> [1,2,3, *[4,5,6]]
File "<stdin>", line 1
[1,2,3, *[4,5,6]]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why doesn't the `*` operator:

```
[1, 2, 3, *[4, 5, 6]] give [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

whereas when the `*` operator is used with a function call it does expand:

```
f(*[4, 5, 6]) is equivalent to f(4, 5, 6)
```

There is a similarity between the `+` and the `*` when using lists but not when extending a list with another type.

For example:

```
# This works
gen = (x for x in range(10))

def hello(*args):
    print args    
hello(*gen)

# but this does not work
[] + gen
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "generator") to list
```

Comment: What are you expecting from that usage? I mean, why would you want to do that?

Comment: ok ill update my question

Comment: It looks like two separate question: the first is more syntax related, the second is just the behaviour of `list.__add__`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unpacking in list, dict, set, and tuple literals has been added in Python `3.5`, as described in **[PEP 448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448)**:

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) on Windows (64 bits).

>>> [1, 2, 3, *[4, 5, 6]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#disadvantages) are some explanations for the rationale behind this change. Note that this does not make `*[1, 2, 3]` equivalent to `1, 2, 3` in all contexts. Python's syntax is not intended to work that way.

Comment: use full info, but we discussing `python-2.7` ( see tags in question)

Comment: Seems like they hadn't considered the use of the * within a container when making python 2.7?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko this answers the question as asked. The OP wants to know the reasoning, not how to do it in another way in Py2.7.

Answer (score 5):

The asterisk `*` **isn't simply** unary operator, it's  **argument-unpacking operator** for [functions definitions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and [functions calls](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#calls).

So `*` supposed to be used **only** to work with function params and **not with** lists, tuples etc.

**NOTE:** starting from python3.5,  `*` could be used not only with functions params, [@B. M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767282/355230)'s answer greatly describes that change in python.

If you need to concat lists use concatenation instead `list1 + list2` to get desired result.
To concatenate list and **generator** simply pass `generator` to `list` type object, prior concatenating with another list:

```
gen = (x for x in range(10))
[] + list(gen)
```

Comment: It works in function calls as well as function definitions. It seems a bit like you're implying it only works in the latter case, so you might wnat to edit wording.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thanks, for correction i've updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported. Python 3 gives a better message (though Python 2 does not support `*` in the left part of an assignment, afaik):

```
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
>>> [1,2,3, *[4,5,6]]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
>>>
```

> `f(*[4,5,6])` is equivalent to `f(4,5,6)`

Function argument unfolding is a special case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out python 3, I have just tried it out and it does work in python 3.5.1  >>> [*[1,2,3,4]] => [1, 2, 3, 4] I wasnt aware of that. It even works with generators :) very cool [1,2,3, (x for x in range(10))]