# Insert array index into transposed array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the array:

```
[[2,1,5,2], 
 [1,4,2,1],
 [4,5,5,7],
 [1,5,9,3]]
```

I am trying to transpose the array to shape (16, 3) where the first two elements in the resulting array are the index numbers, and the last is the value. eg:

`[[0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 5], [3, 0, 2], [0, 1, 4], ....]`

Is this possible with a numpy function or similar? Or I have to do this with my own function?

Working example code:

```
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[2,1,5,2],
                [1,4,2,1],
                [4,5,5,7],
                [1,5,9,3]])

dst = np.array([])


for x in range(src.shape[0]):
    for y in range(src.shape[1]):
        dst = np.append(dst, [[y, x, src[x][y]]])

print(dst.reshape(16,3))
```

Comment: Note on terminology: "transpose" on an array means to swap the rows and columns. This isn't what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: There *is* a numpy function for that:

You can use [`numpy.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html):

```
dst = np.array([[*reversed(x), y] for x, y in np.ndenumerate(src)])
print(dst)
#[[0 0 2]
# [1 0 1]
# [2 0 5]
# [3 0 2]
# [0 1 1]
# [1 1 4]
# [2 1 2]
# [3 1 1]
# [0 2 4]
# [1 2 5]
# [2 2 5]
# [3 2 7]
# [0 3 1]
# [1 3 5]
# [2 3 9]
# [3 3 3]]
```

`ndenumerate` will return an iterator yielding pairs of array coordinates and values. You will first need to reverse the coordinates for your desired output. Next [unpack the coordinates into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767282/5858851)<sup>1</sup> with the value and use a list comprehension to consume the iterator.

---

**Original Answer**

You can try:

```
dst = np.column_stack(zip(*[*reversed(np.indices(src.shape)), src])).T
print(dst)
#[[0 0 2]
# [1 0 1]
# [2 0 5]
# [3 0 2]
# [0 1 1]
# [1 1 4]
# [2 1 2]
# [3 1 1]
# [0 2 4]
# [1 2 5]
# [2 2 5]
# [3 2 7]
# [0 3 1]
# [1 3 5]
# [2 3 9]
# [3 3 3]]
```

---

**Explanation**

First, use [`numpy.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to get an array representing the indices of a grid with the shape of `src`.

```
print(np.indices(src.shape))
#[[[0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1]
#  [2 2 2 2]
#  [3 3 3 3]]
#
# [[0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3]]]
```

We can reverse these (since that's the order you want in your final output), and [unpack into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767282/5858851)<sup>1</sup> that also contains `src`.

Then `zip` all of the elements of this list to get the `(col, row, val)` triples. We can stack these together using [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html).

```
list(zip(*[*reversed(np.indices(src.shape)), src]))
#[(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([2, 1, 5, 2])),
# (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([1, 1, 1, 1]), array([1, 4, 2, 1])),
# (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([2, 2, 2, 2]), array([4, 5, 5, 7])),
# (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([3, 3, 3, 3]), array([1, 5, 9, 3]))]
```

Finally transpose ([`numpy.ndarray.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html)) to get the final output.

**Notes**:

1. Unpacking into a `list` is only available in python 3.5+

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a function in numpy for that, but you can use list comprehension to easily build that array:

```
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[2,1,5,2],
                [1,4,2,1],
                [4,5,5,7],
                [1,5,9,3]])

dst = np.array([ [y, x, src[x][y]] 
                 for x in range(src.shape[0]) 
                 for y in range(src.shape[1])])

print(dst.reshape(16,3))
```

Hope this can help.