# Invalid syntax after moving python script to new Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I had this code running successfully on a Raspberry Pi:

```py
from subprocess import check_output
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import threading

cmd = ['/usr/bin/ebusctl', 'read', '-f']
header = ['Date','Time','Flow','Return','Flame']

with open('/media/pi/VAILLANT/vaillant_log.csv', 'w', newline = '') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

def read_ebus():
    threading.Timer(10.0, read_ebus).start()

    date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    time = datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    flow_temp =  float(check_output([*cmd, 'FlowTemp', 'temp']))
    return_temp =  float(check_output([*cmd, 'ReturnTemp', 'temp']))
    flame =  check_output([*cmd, 'Flame'])

    data = [date,time,flow_temp,return_temp,flame]

    with open('/media/pi/VAILLANT/vaillant_log.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(data)
read_ebus()
```

When I try to run it on adifferent RPi I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python vaillant/vaillant3.py
File "vaillant/vaillant3.py", line 18
flow_temp =  float(check_output([*cmd, 'FlowTemp', 'temp']))
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas why this is happening please?

Comment: What version of python do you have on the RPi where the error occurs?

Comment: Specifically, does `python` run Python 2 on the device where this is not working?

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766677/python-splat-unpack-operator-in-python-cannot-be-used-in-an-expression) help at all?

Comment: @tripleee it's 2.7.16

Comment: If you have to use python 2, you could change the code to be like: `cmd + ['FlowTemp', 'temp']`

Comment: @quamrana thanks for your help. I will update to a newer version of python.